# Complex known string matching in JS using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working on a name replacement script for an online TTRPG platform, but I am very poor at Regex.

Currently I have the following code which replaces the name correctly in many instances:

```js
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + data.alias + "\\b", "gi"), replacement);
```

In this example:
`data.alias` is the name of the "creature", this could be as simple as something like `Bandit` or as complex as something like `Goblin King (Variant 1)`.

`replacement` is a user selected string such as `Unknown Creature`

A sample `el` might look something like:
`<h4>Bandit</h4>`

or it might be:
`<p>The Goblin King (Variant 1) is known to lair in the dank, dark cave</p>`

The following problems are causing me grief trying to find the correct matching pattern:
 1. For a common-word name like `bandit` I do not want the pattern to match a word such as `banditry`
 2. For names that have non-word characters (such as `(`) my current word-boundary match fails. I'm not certain if simply escaping all special characters is a smart choice

Is there a pattern that can match names accurately given that the name is a known quantity?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--you're replacing a known explicit string, why can't you just use `replace` with that string?

Comment: @DaveNewton the `replace` function only replaces a single instance of a string unless you use a regex version of the string with a `g` global tag

Comment: @errational what is the purpose of the `"\\b"` at the beginning and end of your Regex?

Comment: @ChrisSandvik I've been through many iterations on this, but I believe it was to remove the "banditry" for "bandit" scenario. I'm assuming you know what it means in RegEx terms, but in case it's unclear it defines a word or string boundary.

Comment: @ChrisSandvik Yes. Without knowing any context there's no way to know if the string may appear multiple times, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just assumed that he wanted to match all because he used the global tag in his example

Comment: Ultimately this will be fairly difficult if you have unbounded input, e.g., "The Bandit, being a bandit, started doing Bandit-like things." Unless you have known boundaries a naive search-and-replace will likely have unintended side-effects almost no matter what.

Comment: @DaveNewton "Fairly difficult" as in "not worth the effort to implement"? At this point I'll probably just stick with what I've got.

Comment: @errational Depends on your requirements and the actual data you're dealing with. It's contextually-dependent replacement if you need exact results; it's tricky. If you can relax your expected output, or have a better way to retrieve the data so you don't have that problem it may be doable.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this if you use negative lookahead and lookbehind instead of word boundaries. You will, however, need to escape special regex characters such as the parentheses in `Goblin King (Variant 1)`.

Give this a try:

`el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("(?![^\\s,.!?;:])" + data.alias + "(?<![^\\s,.!?;:])", "gi"), replacement);`

Demos: https://regex101.com/r/xlvAdt/1 https://regex101.com/r/zvHL1q/1

Basically, the pattern says to look for the given string as long as it's not preceded or followed by anything that isn't a whitespace character or punctuation.

Comment: This is getting very close! I played around and what I think I want instead is a negative **word** lookahead. That way `bandit` would match `bandit,` or `bandit.` but not `banditry`. I'm guessing the simplest way to escape special chars in my target string is just to do a replace on them specifically before passing to the actual regex statement?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you had to deal with punctuation. I'll edit the answer to account for this.

Comment: OK I think I have a plan. It's not perfect, but I think it's getting better. Here's my example: https://regex101.com/r/xlvAdt/5
Basically in my JS I will break up any names with spaces into component groups then do a cascading match on the groups